# Counting number of people in my query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query that finds sports peoples best times in racing etc. My query basically filters out all races apart from personal best times.

I want to show the % of races they have completed over other people in the races

I cant get my head around how to do this so hoping someone could help, this is my code:

```
SELECT tblSourceData.Athlete, Max(tblSourceData.Swim) AS MaxOfSwim, Max(tblSourceData.Bike) AS MaxOfBike, Max(tblSourceData.Run) AS MaxOfRun, Count(tblSourceData.Athlete) AS EventsCompleted
    FROM tblSourceData
    WHERE (((tblSourceData.Gender)="f"))
    GROUP BY tblSourceData.Athlete
    HAVING (((Count(tblSourceData.Athlete))>=5));
```

My Rows in my table are:

```
Athlete
Swim
Run
Bike
Date
Gender
```

-------- ADDED MORE INFO FROM COMMENTS -----------

My query at the moment shows something like this as an example:

```
Name      Swim      Bike       Run       CompletedEvents       %
Dave      43:22    11:23      32:34            46
John      43:23    31:24      11:43            12
```

I want to know the percentage of the average for all athletes who completed races

Thank you in advance

Comment: and what is a race? every row in your table is a race? You must give some more info so we can help you

Comment: "the % of races they have completed over other people in the races".Can you give more info on that too???

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output

Comment: "I want to know the percentage of the average " So if Dave has a best time 43:22 in swim and the average is 41:15 what percentage do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry, im terrible at explaining - I want to work out the % from events completed and the number of athletes listed in the query. So in my example Dave completed 46 events and only two people in the query. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Just to be clear as per above comment `%` for Dave should come out to be 79.31 and for John 20.68?

Comment: Ye I believe thats on the right track to what I need

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tblSourceData.Athlete,
(SELECT Max(tblSourceData.Swim) from tblSourceData) AS MaxOfSwim, 
(SELECT Max(tblSourceData.Bike) from tblSourceData) AS MaxOfBike,
(SELECT Max(tblSourceData.Run) from tblSourceData) AS MaxOfRun,
Count(tblSourceData.Athlete) AS EventsCompleted
FROM tblSourceData
WHERE (((tblSourceData.Gender)="f"))
GROUP BY tblSourceData.Athlete
HAVING (((Count(tblSourceData.Athlete))>=5));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wouldn't it increase load and execution time?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the percentage of every athlete's completed races out of all races you just need to use `SUM()` to sum up all the completed races and then calculate every user's percentage.I could not test it but something like this should work:

```
SELECT tblSourceData.Athlete as Athlete,
       Max(tblSourceData.Swim) AS MaxOfSwim,
       Max(tblSourceData.Bike) AS MaxOfBike, 
       Max(tblSourceData.Run) AS MaxOfRun,
       Count(tblSourceData.Athlete) AS EventsCompleted,
       ROUND((100*Count(tblSourceData.Athlete)/(SELECT SUM(b.eventsCompleted) FROM  (      
           SELECT COUNT(tblSourceData.Athlete) AS EventsCompleted FROM tblSourceData
           WHERE tblSourceData.Gender="f"
           GROUP BY tblSourceData.Athlete
           HAVING Count(tblSourceData.Athlete)>=5
       ) AS b)),2)  AS `percentage` 
       FROM tblSourceData
       WHERE tblSourceData.Gender="f"
       GROUP BY tblSourceData.Athlete
       HAVING Count(tblSourceData.Athlete)>=5
```

Comment: @david I updated my query it should be ok now.You can try it again